# Mysql Join 4 tables and generate boolean field on the fourth one

Tags: mysql

This is what actually driving me crazy.

Three tables: candidats, offres, and candidatures.

There's fourth one called "`cvtheque`" having fields:
`recruteur_id` and `candidat_id` and others..

I want to add a column on results that returns boolean variable

```
if(cvtheque.recruteur_id=candidatures.recruteur_id and    
cvtheque.candidat_id=candidatures.candidat_id)
```

The folowing query returns results cols as:

```
    c_id    sexe    nom_prenom  cv_title    remplissage     offre_id    titre   
    candidature_id  lettre_id   entry_date

    SELECT 
    candidats.id as c_id, candidats.sexe, candidats.nom_prenom, 
    candidats.cv_title, candidats.remplissage, 

    offres.id AS offre_id, offres.titre, 
    candidatures.id as candidature_id, candidatures.lettre_id, candidatures.entry_date

    FROM candidats, offres JOIN candidatures
    WHERE candidatures.candidat_id = candidats.id
    AND candidatures.recruteur_id = '1'
    AND candidatures.offre_id = offres.id 
    ORDER BY candidatures.entry_date desc 
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

what i exactly i want is to add a column Boolean after the last column (`entry_date`) holds a Boolean variable value of the condition (`cvtheque.recruteur_id=candidatures.recruteur_id` and `cvtheque.candidat_id=candidatures.candidat_id`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **CASE WHEN,** which is explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

Or perhaps a simple **IF** will do it -- [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) `SELECT IF(1<2,'yes','no');`

```
SELECT ..... candidatures.entry_date,
IF(cvtheque.recruteur_id=candidatures.recruteur_id 
AND cvtheque.candidat_id=candidatures.candidat_id,'yes','no')
FROM....
```

I am not certain of the syntax for `IF condition1 AND condition2` in MySql.

Try it first without the AND, and when that is working add the AND.

Comment: :( weired, lost on that while not sure if it's the right solution, having troubles applying case statement on the syntax. any further clarifications would be so much appreciated!